# Crear el hash SHA-1 de un formulario

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Muy buenas, me preguntaba como puedo construir este hash. Es para un formulario que cargare como iframe en una web construida en wordpress.

https://developer.globalpay.com/hpp/card-payments#generate-hash

Básicamente lo que busco es crear un hash diferente en cada formulario de compra para luego enviarlo al endpoint, y tiene que ser SHA-1 con los valores concatenados asi: timestamp.merchantid.orderid.amount.currency

El merchantid es estático, lo demas es dinámico. Como debo de construir este tipo de hash para luego pasarle el resutado a un formulario en el campo <input type="hidden" name="SHA1HASH" value=AQUI VA EL HASH

Gracias por la ayuda, con una referencia o guía me sirve para saber como proceder.

Comment: No entiendo bien la pregunta. Cuando dices "no hay forma de encontrar como construir este tipo de hash" te refieres a que no has encontrado una librería para hashear un string con SHA-1? O que no entendiste qué cosas debes hashear? Podrías por favor [edit] tu pregunta y aclararlo? Gracias

Comment: LISTO! espero ahora se entienda

Comment: Sigue sin ser clara la pregunta, dale formato a tu codigo.

Comment: @lekordicosadiluy te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask]. También te sugiero que leas [example] para que podamos entender tu problema. No te tomará mas de 5 minutos de lectura. Saludos

Comment: `echo sha1( implode( ".", [ time(), MERCHANT_ID, $order_id, $amount, $currency ]  )`